# Prevent direct guest-to-guest communication on a virtual network

Tags: linux-kvm, libvirt

How can I create a virtual network where guest cannot directly communicate with other guests?

If you're wondering why: the virtual network has guests that provide services to VPN users. Different user roles have different firewall rules that allow access to particular guests. Some guests allow ssh/rdp, so people could potentially make onward connections from the guest and gain unauthorised access to other guests.

I'm using KVM & libvirt on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libvirt with KVM supports a feature called "nwfilter" which lets you configure quite extensive firewall rules for individual guest network interfaces. Explaining this is beyond the scope of this answer, so its best to just read the online docs:

http://libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html

the majority of stuff you can achieve with iptables/ebtables can be expressed using libvirt's nwfilter rules. So it should be possible to create filter rules that strongly isolate your guests from each other.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer an old question. I had forgotten about this and abandoned the approach, but I'm now positive you've got the solution :)